# MongoDB Remove or Limit fields conditional aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having some issue writing a find/aggregate mongo query where my requirement is to get all the documents but having condition like:

Suppose I have 2 documents:

```
{
  _id: 5ccaa76939d95d395791efd2,
  name: 'John Doe',
  email: 'john.doe@foobar.com',
  private: true
}

{
  _id: 5ccaa76939d95d395791efd2,
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  email: 'jane.doe@foobar.com',
  private: false
}
```

Now the query I am trying to get my head around is if the field `private` is true then when I query I must get all documents except email fields not included if `private` is true, like this:

```
{
 _id: 5ccaa76939d95d395791efd2,
 name: 'John Doe',
 private: true
}

{
 _id: 5ccaa76939d95d395791efd2,
 name: 'Jane Doe',
 email: 'jane.doe@foobar.com',
 private: false
}
```

Tried `$redact`, `$cond`, `$$PRUNE`, `$$DESCEND` in aggregate() as well as came across `$$REMOVE` (looks like it is newest feature) but unable to get the required output. Please help me out with the Query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `$$REMOVE` to remove a field from returned documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
  { "$addFields": {
    "email": {
      "$cond": [
        { "$eq": ["$private", true] },
        "$$REMOVE",
        "$email"
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**`MongoPlayground`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gYCpYWKlUVl)

Comment: thank you so much for this query, this indeed worked.!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Anthony Winzlet, his solution worked like a charm.

If anyone faces same problem and requires to include more than 1 fields, I am doing so by writing this method:

```
function condition(privateFieldLimitationArray, publicFieldLimitationArray) {
  const condition = {};

  privateFieldLimitationArray.map((d, i) => {
    condition[d] = {
      "$cond": [
      { "$eq": ["$private", true] },
      "$$REMOVE",
      publicFieldLimitationArray.includes(d) ? '$$REMOVE' : '$'+d
      ]
    }
  });

  return condition;
}
```

Then, you can use the above function like:

```
const privateLimitationArray = ['updatedAt', 'createdAt', 'email', 'lname', 'friendslist', '__v'];

const publicLimitationArray = ['updatedAt', 'createdAt', '__v'];


YourModel.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            // Your query to find by
          }
        }, {
          "$addFields": condition(privateLimitationArray, publicLimitationArray)
        }
    ])
    .then(result => {
      // handle result
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle error
    });
```